# Column data types changed following "rake db:reset"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Having ballsed up my development database I've just run `rake db:reset`.  This has reset my database as expected, but has also changed `schema.rb` so that every database column that was previously of type `timestamp` is now of type `datetime`.

I have two questions:

1. How could this have happened?
2. What effects, if any, might this have?

I'm running rails 3.0.3.

Comment: Look at your migrations. Had you changed the datatypes manually?

Comment: It could have happened if you changed database types (i.e. you used to use a PostgreSQL db but now you have a SQLite db).  I've also had it happen when importing data from another database.  Not sure why it happened in your case since it should base the reset off the current schema.rb.

Answer (score 0):

I use to follow the below command for resetting the database tables and it doesn't affect any of my timestamps

```
                rake db:migrate:reset
```